# Constructor-arg behavior for spring... Why following behaviour?

Tags: java, spring

```
Rectangle(int x, String y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}

Rectangle(String y, int z){
    this.z=z;
    this.y=y;
}
```

In above code, I used folllowing in the xml:-

```
<constructor-arg type="int" value="10"/>
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="10"/>
```

the constructor that works in this case is the second one... Why? How the spring decides here which one to call

Answer (score 5):

Basically this happens because **the order in which the arguments appear in the bean configuration file will not be considered when invoking the constructor**.

**To solve this** problem you can **use the index attribute** to specify the constructor argument index. Here is the bean configuration file after adding the index attribute:

```
<bean id="rectangle" class="com.shape.rectangle" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="10"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.String" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: 10X Yuri... I got that the order is not preferred.. but what else is preferred then,,, I mean how this gets called internally?

Comment: As it said in the answer that 'the order in which the arguments appear in the bean configuration file will not be considered while invoking the constructor.'